# How to add image icon on custom page link on layout?

Tags: layout, block, magento2

I have create 'page' link on header.links can show on homepage headers.
But I could like add image icon next my 'service-center' link. How to make it?

[image]

```
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="service-center" >
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Service center</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">service-center</argument>
            </arguments>

        </block>
```

Answer (score 2):

there are 2 ways to do this

1) You can add css class in link using :

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="service-center" >
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Service center</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">service-center</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">service-center</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

after that you need to write CSS for the ICON/Image

2) You need to define template .phtml file for this.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="service-center" template="YourCompany_YourModule::account/customer.phtml" />
```

Make Sure to change namespace defined : **YourCompany_YourModule**

Comment: Thanks your response
For 1) is about define css service-center class on my css file?

For 2) I try to call the template, it nothing to display on page. 

my phtml as following:
        <li class="service-center">
        <img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images\chat.png'); ?>' alt="service-center">
 <a href="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getHref())?>"
        <?php if ($title = $block->getTitle()):?> title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($title))?>"<?php endif;?>>
        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($block->getLabel()))?>
        </a>
        </li>

Comment: 1) will add class in html with link

Comment: Good answer, I will use first. but the fact I dont know how to add a dynamic count to the menu link label like 
"> Messages (*4 new*)"
how to do this?